# Empty (white) line under UITableView after close MPMoviewPlayer from fullscreen mode

Tags: iphone, uitableview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have simple application with list of movies in UITableView. When I select some row, I open modal view controller what present MPMoviePlayerController.

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:playerController animated:YES];
```

Also I set observer to catch message when player is finish playing.
When playing is finished, I make

```
[self dismisModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If I click "Done" in player control, all work great. But if it's finish playing self in fullscreen mode I get white line in bottom of UITableView cels which have height 20px like status bar. 
Somebody have idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Your UITableViewCells have a height of 20? The code you provided would not have anything to do with a white space when the MPMoviePlayerController is dismissed, try posting more of the code you are using throughout your view.

Comment: It's look like UITableView "jump" up for 20px after moviewPlayer modal view is dismissed. But only in case, if it's finish play in fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution.
Before dismiss modal view just make

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

It's solve my problem.
Also, when on viewDidLoad I call

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

For show MPMoviePlayer on full screen.