# MPMoviePlayer leaving a space above NavigationBar

Tags: iphone, xcode, mpmovieplayer

Screenshot found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fru4x.png

So I have a UITableViewController pushing a UIViewController that has a MPMoviePlayer object in it. What i've discovered is that when I load in the MPMoviePlayer as a subview, it creates a statusbar. This statusbar pushes down the navigationbar a the top, causing the white space. I've looked at a bunch of different topics on stackoverflow and nothing seems to work:

[iPhone: Weird space at the top of UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041060/iphone-weird-space-at-the-top-of-uinavigationcontroller)

[Not sure why UIView is being nudged up by around 10px](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054539/not-sure-why-uiview-is-being-nudged-up-by-around-10px)

[Empty (white) line under UITableView after close MPMoviewPlayer from fullscreen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671881/empty-white-line-under-uitableview-after-close-mpmoviewplayer-from-fullscreen-m)

[Hide StatusBar from MPMoviePlayerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653236/hide-statusbar-from-mpmovieplayercontroller)

The UIViewController is being pushed with the following code (PresetViewController.m):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    //PresetNode *tempNode = [appDelegate.presetData objectAtIndex:row];

   ..... SOME DATA IS LOADED HERE

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];
    MoviePlayer *player = [[MoviePlayer alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil andVideoArray: presetVideoURLs];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:player animated:NO];
    [player playVideoAtIndex:0];
    [player release];

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

When the view controller loads, for some reason it loads in a statusbar at the top of its view even though I use this code in MoviePlayer.m:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[self becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

I set the movie to landscape mode and play it. Then I check to see if the done button is pressed. If the done button is pressed, I pop the view. For some reason, when the view gets popped, the uitableviewcontroller behind it gets pushed down by a few pixels. The statusbar the movieplayer created pushes everything down. Here is the movieplayer code (MoviePlayer.m):

```
-(void) playVideoAtIndex: (NSInteger)index{

NSString *rootPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString *filePath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent: [self.movieArray objectAtIndex:index]];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];
self.yourMoviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: fileURL];

[yourMoviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];



[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden: YES];

yourMoviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
[[yourMoviePlayer view] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2)];
self.yourMoviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.frame;

[yourMoviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:NO];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(checkForNextMovie:)                                                 
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object:yourMoviePlayer];

[[self view]addSubview:yourMoviePlayer.view];
//[[self navigationController] presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self];
//---play movie---
[yourMoviePlayer play];    

}

-(void) checkForNextMovie:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
 removeObserver:self
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object:player];

NSNumber *reason = [[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey];

[yourMoviePlayer release];
if((currentIndex+1) == [self.movieArray count] || [reason intValue] == MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited){
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
    [player.view removeFromSuperview];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden: NO];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    //self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation != self.interfaceOrientation) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation animated:NO];
    }
}
else{
    currentIndex++;
    [self playVideoAtIndex: currentIndex];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the viewController.view's frame (viewController.view.frame) to a CGRect taking up the whole screen:

```
viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 320, 480);
```

Manually setting the size should get rid of the white space.

Comment: I ended up using an affinetransform to move just the UINavigationBar up 20 px. Thanks for your help though!